# Why TextInput's `.clear()` doesn't trigger `onChangeText` callback?

Tags: react-native

I am programmatically clearing the TextInput's value via `.clear()` method.
I also subscribed my state to `onChangeText` but on `.clear()` invocation, my state doesn't change.

Why `.clear()` doesn't trigger `onChangeText`? Isn't it changing the text value?

Example:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const ref = useRef();

  const handlePress = () => {
    ref.current.clear();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={setValue} ref={ref} />;
      <Button
        title="clear"
        onPress={handlePress} // <<< when this is called, onChangeText doesn't called?
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general across multiple different APIs and event systems, when you change the value of a field/control *via code*, it doesn't trigger any event handlers related to that change. (There are APIs/systems that are exception to that general rule, but they're rare.) The event handlers are there for when the change is done via the user operating on the field/control in the UI. For example, with a DOM `input` element, setting the `value` property changes the value, but doesn't trigger any events (such as `change` or `input`); submitting a form via its `submit` function doesn't trigger a `submit` event. React Native is just following the same pattern in their fields/controls.

Comment: Thank you, so it's just a API convention.